# Where is the file after create by "$service->spreadsheets->create($requestBody)"

Tags: laravel-5, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

Thank you very much for reading this, its quite long!

1. I run my function:

   ```
   public function createSpreadSheet()
   {
           $client = $this->getClient();
           $service = new \Google_Service_Sheets($client);
           // TODO: Assign values to desired properties of `requestBody`:
           $requestBody = new \Google_Service_Sheets_Spreadsheet();
           $response = $service->spreadsheets->create($requestBody);
           echo '<pre>', var_export($response, true), '</pre>', "\n";
   }
   ```
2. I got a result:

   ```
   Google_Service_Sheets_Spreadsheet::__set_state(array(
   'collection_key' => 'sheets',
   'developerMetadataType' => 'Google_Service_Sheets_DeveloperMetadata',
   'developerMetadataDataType' => 'array',
   'namedRangesType' => 'Google_Service_Sheets_NamedRange',
   'namedRangesDataType' => 'array',
   'propertiesType' => 'Google_Service_Sheets_SpreadsheetProperties',
   'propertiesDataType' => '',
   'sheetsType' => 'Google_Service_Sheets_Sheet',
   'sheetsDataType' => 'array',
   'spreadsheetId' => '1QlBQo_YHQpiiMBWn6b6wSMVWkiFRx4grJhPParXUUSU',
   'spreadsheetUrl' => 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QlBQo_YHQpiiMBWn6b6wSMVWkiFRx4grJhPParXUUSU/edit',
   'internal_gapi_mappings' => 
   array (
   ),
   modelData' => 
   array (
   ),
   'processed' => 
   array (
   ),
   'properties' => 
   Google_Service_Sheets_SpreadsheetProperties::__set_state(array(
   'autoRecalc' => 'ON_CHANGE',
   'defaultFormatType' => 'Google_Service_Sheets_CellFormat',
   'defaultFormatDataType' => '',
   'iterativeCalculationSettingsType' => 'Google_Service_Sheets_IterativeCalculationSettings',
   'iterativeCalculationSettingsDataType' => '',
   'locale' => 'en_US',
   'timeZone' => 'Etc/GMT',
   'title' => 'Untitled spreadsheet',
   'internal_gapi_mappings' => 
   array (
   ),
   'modelData' => 
   array (
   ),
   'processed' => 
   array (
   ),
   'defaultFormat' => 
   Google_Service_Sheets_CellFormat::__set_state(array(
   'backgroundColorType' => 'Google_Service_Sheets_Color',
   'backgroundColorDataType' => '',
   'bordersType' => 'Google_Service_Sheets_Borders',
   'bordersDataType' => '',
   'horizontalAlignment' => NULL,
   'hyperlinkDisplayType' => NULL,
   'numberFormatType' => 'Google_Service_Sheets_NumberFormat',
   'numberFormatDataType' => '',
   .........
   .........
   ))
   ```
3. I access to the link it returned:
   'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QlBQo_YHQpiiMBWn6b6wSMVWkiFRx4grJhPParXUUSU/edit'
4. it gives me this 'request access' page, then I press the request access
5. I open my email and get this:
   Your message wasn't delivered to xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com because the domain admanager-1x3x71x4x27x4.iam.gserviceaccount.com couldn't be found. Check for typos or unnecessary spaces and try again.
6. Is there something wrong and what should I do? I just want to open the file and check where it is.

Thank you very much!